# Satellite Tracker on ESP8266 issue

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, tracker, satellite

I've been trying to make the satellite tracker from the link below but when I run my code, I constantly get an error on the serial monitor.

https://github.com/CactusProjects/SatelliteTracker

I've tried to run the code on a Wemos D1 mini and NodeMCU V1.0 12-F, code uploaded with Arduino EDI 1.8.15
I've got all the libraries and the code compiles normally and uploads normally.

When running I get the following error in the serial monitor

```
Entering Setup
Entering Setup
No LSM303 (compass) detected.
Assuming Elevation is set to 20°
No Compass Present, Heading set to 0°
Compass Heading: 0.00°
Attempting to connect to WiFi
WiFi Connecting. . . 0
WiFi Connecting. . . 1
WiFi Connecting. . . 2
WiFi Connecting. . . 3
WiFi Connecting. . . 4
WiFi Connecting. . . 5
WiFi Connecting. . . 6
WiFi Connecting. . . 7
WiFi connected, IP address: 192.168.0.159
Today: 4
timeNow (unix timestamp): 1621490563

HTTP Request #0 is for ISS
Requesting URL: http://www.celestrak.com/satcat/tle.php?CATNR=25544
[HTTP] GET... code: 200
Recieved HTTP Payload for: ISS (ZARYA)             
1 25544U 98067A   21140.04032925  .00001407  00000-0  33666-4 0  9993
2 25544  51.6437 121.9403 0003181  20.5176  89.9422 15.49024471284232

Back from getting TLE for: ISS
1 25544U 98067A   21140.04032925  .00001407  00000-0  33666-4 0  9993
2 25544  51.6437 121.9403 0003181  20.5176  89.9422 15.49024471284232

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Exception (0):
epc1=0x40205742 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffc60 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 0190
3ffffdf0:  3ffef0c8 3ffef0c8 00000000 40205742  
3ffffe00:  4826f70a 40a58085 00000000 40201391  
3ffffe10:  29694578 419c857d 53b4fc98 4188ba74  
3ffffe20:  9e64e6bd 4142c36d 9f2847e7 4142c36d  
3ffffe30:  9ec6536c 4142c36d 00000000 7ff80000  
3ffffe40:  64c2e190 40243cd7 00000000 00000000  
3ffffe50:  00000000 7ff80000 025b1a9d 40677d2c  
3ffffe60:  fd85cd34 4060ed36 e7c75dd0 4054b214  
3ffffe70:  00000000 7ff80000 00000000 00000000  
3ffffe80:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3ffffe90:  3ffef0c8 40768000 00000000 4020e35c  
3ffffea0:  57b405d0 3fbf58d2 aa3f2101 3ffef4c8  
3ffffeb0:  00000000 40768000 3ffef0c8 402051bf  
3ffffec0:  d2f1a9fc 3fb0624d 603dd1bb 4142c36d  
3ffffed0:  3ffef100 00000005 3ffe8eec 40216020  
3ffffee0:  bd54dafd 40b819a8 6d8730c4 c0890ac4  
3ffffef0:  8344ba4d c0a58087 b9e54e92 bfdace28  
3fffff00:  4e957678 bfc08860 c6bf9100 407ac733  
3fffff10:  603dd1bb 4142c36d 3ffef6d8 3ffef836  
3fffff20:  3ffe85cc 00000045 3ffefbc8 3ffe85cc  
3fffff30:  3ffef0c8 3ffef6ac 3ffef0c8 00000000  
3fffff40:  3ffef0c8 3ffef6ac 3ffefbc8 402028a4  
3fffff50:  00000000 40500000 feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffff60:  00000000 0024002f 00000000 00000000  
3fffff70:  0024002f 00000000 feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffff80:  40496eb3 80000000 40160103 20000000  
3fffff90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe 3ffefc58  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffefc44 40214730  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe87f8 40100e39  
<<<stack<<<

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------
```

After looking at the error in Arduino EDI "ESP Exception Decoder" I get the following error message but I am stuck at this point.

```
Exception 0: Illegal instruction
PC: 0x40205742
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000

Decoding stack results
0x40201391: Predict(int) at D:\Arduino Projects\tracker_main/tracker_main.ino line 408
0x4020e35c: Sgp4::visible() at D:\Arduino Projects\libraries\Sgp4-Library-master\src\visible.cpp line 197
0x402051bf: Sgp4::findsat(double) at D:\Arduino Projects\libraries\Sgp4-Library-master\src\sgp4pred.cpp line 87
0x40216020: uart_write(uart_t*, char const*, size_t) at C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\cores\esp8266\uart.cpp line 546
0x402028a4: setup() at D:\Arduino Projects\tracker_main/tracker_main.ino line 157
0x40214730: loop_wrapper() at C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp line 198
```

At the moment there is no hardware (sensors, stepper motor) connected to the NodeMCU, I only uploaded the code at first to see if I got this working.

I hope to find some help here.

Comment: Doubt you will get help here. What I would do is check if the char arrays are large enough to pick up the satellite names. I would redefine hardcoded sizes with #DEFINE statements and use these to in the array declarations. You can then easily change the numbers to test if it fixes things by avoiding a buffer overflow. Just guessing here but who knows. You may have to get your hands dirty and debug that thing.

Comment: Hi, thank you. For some unexplanable reason I got it working when uploading the sketch via Visial Studio Code + Platformio. I can start working on the hardware and 3d printing.